# Авторизация на сайте. Передача логина и пароля в URL

Tags: php, html, url

Сразу уточню, что речь идет о домашнем сайте автоматизации "Умный дом" в локальной сети дома, и кражи открыто переданного пароля тут не уместны.
На странице вставляю видео с камеры по средствам тега img

```
<img src="http://admin:@10.10.10.10:9999/cameras/0/video">
```

Это работало на старой версии Хром. После обновления хром отключил поддержку такого способа авторизации. В результате старые устройства показывают видео, а новые вообще не понимают URL.

Вариант

```
<img src="http://10.10.10.10:9999/cameras/0/video">
```

работает везде, но только после заполнения полей авторизации.
Редактировать код источника я не могу. Это IP камеры и видео регистраторы. Способа передать логин в параметрах после адреса вида ...?login="zzz"&password="xxx" для этих устройств я не нашел.
Сайт умного дома работает на Апачи + php.

Comment: Написать локальную проксю которая будет ходить в камеру с авторизацией.

Comment: Но вообще это не «умный» дом, а «дырявый» дом

Comment: @Alexey Ten Камера, Сервер и терминал в локальной сети. Сеть защищена. Где тут дыры?

Comment: @Alexey Ten Порт из вне закрыт

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Рекомендую использовать [ответ](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42724593/696034) с англоязычного SO:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.responseType = 'blob'; //so you can access the response like a normal URL
xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (xhr.readyState == XMLHttpRequest.DONE && xhr.status == 200) {
        var img = document.createElement('img');
        img.src = URL.createObjectURL(xhr.response); //create <img> with src set to the blob
        document.body.appendChild(img);
    }
};
xhr.open('GET', 'http://images.example.com/my_secure_image.png', true);
xhr.setRequestHeader('SecretPassword', 'password123');
xhr.send();
```

Comment: Большое спасибо! Пробую этот способ.